# Circular Doubly Linked List why am I stuck in a loop?

Tags: java, data-structures, doubly-linked-list, circular-list

```
public class LinkedList<E> {
    private Node<E> head;
    private Node<E> tail;

    /* Inserts*/
    public void insertAtHead(E data)
    {
        Node<E> newNode=new Node<E>(data);
        if(this.head==null)
        {
            this.head=newNode;
            //newNode.nextNode=this.head; <--- Here is error cause
            this.tail=this.head;
        }
        else {
            newNode.prevNode = this.tail;
            this.head.prevNode = newNode;
            newNode.nextNode = this.head;
            this.head = newNode;
            System.out.println("tail.next is: " + this.tail.nextNode);
        }
    }
```

To my understanding, I must point the tail of the list to the head node when implementing a circular linked list. This is the implementation of a doubly circular linked list I have and the commented out line is what I do not understand why is causing an error. It seems like the tail is either null or getting stuck in an infinite loop, can someone help me understand please? thank you

Comment: this.tail.nextNode = newNode; I think is missing from the else statement.

Comment: I tried that as well but tail.nextNode still giving me an infinite loop.

Answer (score 0):

```
public void insertAtHead(E data)
    {
        Node<E> newNode=new Node<E>(data);
        if(this.head==null)
        {
            this.head=newNode;
            newNode.nextNode=this.head; // this should NOT be the bug place
            newNode.prevNode=this.head; // add this
            this.tail=this.head;
        }
        else {
            newNode.prevNode = this.tail;
            this.head.prevNode = newNode;
            newNode.nextNode = this.head;
            this.head = newNode;
            tail.nextNode = this.head // add this
            System.out.println("tail.next is: " + this.tail.nextNode);
        }
    }
```

Comment: It's still going into an infinite loop. :(

Comment: @Chabba put the whole code then .. let debug this out !

Comment: ahh i think it's in my toString method, let me attempt to fix

Answer (score 0):

Error was with my length and toString methods small modification, thanks for help.